# How to log the number of available/used threads in a spring boot (tomcat) based application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a spring boot config where you can log the number of available/used threads the app server currently has?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the actuator framework.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then you have to enable tomcat JXM metrics in `application.properties` and expose the metrics endpoint

```
server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,metrics
```

The go to http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/ and you will see all the available metrics.

For example current threads http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/tomcat.threads.current

Comment: That a good point, I know actuator provides a lot of functionality, I will give it a try. Is it possible to disable all other features beside the thread metrics?

Comment: ```{
  "name" : "tomcat.threads.current",
  "baseUnit" : "threads",
  "measurements" : [ {
    "statistic" : "VALUE",
    "value" : 10.0
  } ],
  "availableTags" : [ {
    "tag" : "name",
    "values" : [ "http-nio-8082" ]
  } ]
}

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon. That should do. I only had to exclude security classes since I am using a custom one. 
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })